# Is there a way in tensorflow to load batches of data each time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

So I'm running tensorflow 2+ python in google colab.

Each of my data file is a 3d image with shape [563, 563, 563, 1], so loading all of them throws a resource exhaustion error.

I've spent days and hours searching for a way to load only a batch of my dataset as tensor and unloading/loading new batch each iteration. I'm guessing there might be a way using tf.data.Dataset.list_files, but I can't find the exact way.

Is there any good suggestions on a way to do it or any documents I could try to read? I've read the tf.data document from tensorflow, but couldn't find the information I needed.

Thank you!

## Edit

so this is the function I want to use to load my image

```
def load_image(ind):
    file_brain = "/content/drive/My Drive/brain/" + str(ind) + ".mgz"
    file_mask = "/content/drive/My Drive/mask/" + str(ind) + ".mgz"
    data_brain, affine = load_nifti(file_brain)
    data_mask, affine = load_nifti(file_mask)
    data_brain = affine_transform(data_brain, affine)
    data_mask = affine_transform(data_mask, affine)
    data_brain = normalize(data_brain)
    data_brain = zoom(data_brain, (563/256, 563/256, 563/256))
    data_brain = tf.expand_dims(data_brain, axis=-1)
    data_mask = tf.expand_dims(data_mask, axis=-1)
    return data_brain, data_mask
```

and this was the way I was loading the dataset before, which exhausted the resource;

```
def create_dataset():
    train_data = []
    train_label = []
    test_data = []
    test_label = []
    test_n = np.random.randint(1, 10, 1)
    for i in range(1, 10):
        data_brain, data_mask = load_image(i)
        if i in test_n:
            test_data.append(data_brain)
            test_label.append(data_mask)
            continue
        train_data.append(data_brain)
        train_label.append(data_mask)
        shifted_data = data_brain + tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05)
        scaled_data = data_brain * tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=0.85, maxval=1.3)
        train_data.append(shifted_data)
        train_label.append(data_mask)
        train_data.append(scaled_data)
        train_label.append(data_mask)
"""
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_data)
train_label = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_label)
test_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test_data)
test_label = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test_label)
return train_data, train_label, test_data, test_label
"""
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried using [tf.data.Dataset.from_generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator)?

Comment: Thank you! But wouldn't the from_generator also load all the data before starting to feed them through the network?

What I want is,
read a batch of image data as tensor -> feed through network -> update weights -> delete the read data and read another batch of image data -> iterate

Comment: tf.data processes dataset elements as a stream, only holding as much data in memory as is necessary. Can you share the code you are using to read your data? Certain operations require multiple elements to be loaded in memory simultaneously. For example, `shuffle(n)` holds `n` elements in memory so that it can randomly sample the next element to produce.

Comment: @AAudibert added the code in the question! Thank you :)
So if I understand correctly, if I for example use tf.data.Dataset.list_files to load my images, it will only load the batch of images when needed? If so, how would I tell them what function it needs to use to load the images?

Comment: As Oliver suggested, you can use `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` to load just one element at a time. `from_generator`, uses a [python generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) so that it doesn't need to load all the data at once.

Comment: @AAudibert So if I make a function that loads a batch of data as a tensor, use it as the generator function, it will have the behavior I want?

Comment: Yes, you make a function that yields the data tensors. Definitely check out the [Dataset.from_generator docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator)

Comment: Great!! Thanks could you add it as an answer?